# Why does my mac big sur allow non-root to listen at port 80?

Tags: macos, tcp, port

I don't know why my mac big sur could ***ALLOW*** non-root application to listen at port 80?
That is ***nc -l 80*** could run successfully.
That would fail before, I don't know when/what made it behaving like this.

Comment: See https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18302380